# How to compare substrings of 2 different strings?

Tags: python, computer-science

I'm trying to compare 2 last names and see which comes first in alphabetical order

- Grace Hopper
- Katherine Johnson

How would I extract the second word in any string with [firstword: secondword] format?

Comment: I understand simply asking question is easy. But please, at least read some basic tutorial of python before asking, for example https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp

Answer (score 1):

To extract the last name, you can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the name. It will, by default, split on whitespace:

```
fullname = 'Grace Hopper'
first_name, last_name = fullname.split()
```

Then, to compare alphabetically, simply compare the lastnames:

```
if last_name_1 < last_name_2:
    ...
```

Or, use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort all names in a list of names:

```
fullnames = 'Grace Hopper', 'Katherine Johnson'

sorted_fullnames = sorted(fullnames, key=lambda fullname: fullname.split()[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to get the last names from the full names.
If a person "1" has name "ABC DEF";
Another person "2" has name "PQR STU";

You can tokenize the string by using split() command.

```
person1 = "ABC DEF"
person2 = "PQR STU"
name1   = person1.split(" ")
name2   = person2.split(" ")
```

Now the results will be,

```
print(name1)
>>> ['ABC', 'DEF']
print(name2)
>>> ['PQR', 'STU']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = 'Grace Hopper Katherine Johnson'

result = min(s.split()[1::2])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Hopper
```

Note that it's case sensitive (`A` < `a`). For a case insensitive version:

```
result = min(s.split()[1::2], key=str.lower)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.split` function to split string into words.

```
In [1]: a="Grace Hopper"

In [2]: b="Katherine Johnson"

In [3]: a.split()
Out[3]: ['Grace', 'Hopper']

In [4]: b.split()
Out[4]: ['Katherine', 'Johnson']

In [6]: a.split()[1]
Out[6]: 'Hopper'

In [8]: b.split()[1]
Out[8]: 'Johnson'

In [9]: a.split()[1] < b.split()[1]
Out[9]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way to do this is to use [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
>   string.
>
> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

---

For instance:

```
>>> name = "Grace Hopper"
>>> name = name.split()
>>> name
>>> ["Grace", "Hopper"]
```

If you want to compare by alphabetical order several strings, just use one of the comparison operators:

```
>>> name1 = "Stan"
>>> name2 = "Viktor"
>>> name1 > name2
>>> False
```

You're getting this result because of `ord("S") < ord("V")`,  [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) built-in function returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character.